# How do I prove $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A) \leq \frac{1}{c}\int_A f(x) d\mu(x)$.?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be a measurable function and $A$ a measurable set in the measure space $(X,M, \mu)$. Prove that for every $c>0$ the following inequality holds

$\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A) \leq \frac{1}{c}\int_A f(x) d\mu(x)$.

I know

$\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A)= \int_{X} \mathbb{X}_{\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A\}}(y) d \mu(y) $

Can anyone suggest how do I solve the given result?

Answer (score 2):

**As stated, the result is wrong. Take for example $f$ defined on $A=[0,1]$ constant and equal to $-1$, $c=1/2$ and $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure.**

The result is correct if you suppose $f$ non negative as you then have:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_A f d\mu &= \int_{A \cap \{f(x) \gt c\}} f d\mu + \int_{A \cap \{f(x) \le c\}} f d\mu\\
&\ge \int_{A \cap \{f(x) \gt c\}} f d\mu\\
&\ge c \mu(\{x \in X \mid f(x)\gt c\} \cap A)
\end{aligned}$$

and therefore the desired result.

Comment: On the set it is stated that $f>c>0$ which is the hipothesys, so it is already supposed the function is non negative on our measurable set.

Comment: @NaveMozza The inequality $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A) \leq \frac{1}{c}\int_A f(x) d\mu(x)$ is wrong in general. In particular if $f$ is always negative. I don’t see in the hypothesis anything related to the sign of $f $ on $A$. Therefore $\int_A f \ d\mu$ can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Notice that $\chi _{\{x:f(x)>c\}}=\chi _{\{x:\frac{f(x)}{c}>1\}}\leq 1 <\frac{f(x)}{c}$ if $x$ is in $\{x\in X: f(x)>c\}.$
Also $\chi _{A\cap B}=\chi _A\cdot \chi _B.$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $c>0$:
$$c\cdot \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A)=c\cdot  \int_{X} \mathbb{X}_{\{x\in X: f(x)>c\} \cap A\}}(y) d \mu(y)=$$
$$=c\cdot \int_{X} \mathbb{X}_{\{x\in X: f(x)>c\}}(y)\mathbb{X}_A(y) d \mu(y) =\int_{A} c\cdot\mathbb{X}_{\{x\in X: f(x)>c\}}(y) d \mu(y)\le$$
$$\le\int_{A\cap \{x\in X: f(x)>c\} } f(y) d \mu(y)$$
The result can be extended to what you wrote if $f\ge 0$ on $A$.

Comment: The inequality $\int_{A} c\cdot\mathbb{X}_{\{x\in X: f(x)>c\}}(y) d \mu(y)\le\int_{A} f(y) d \mu(y)$ isn’t true in general. In particular if $f$ is always negative.

Comment: You are right, I edited it to what I had in mind while writing it.